# Why isn't my smoke simulation interacting with other objects properly?

Tags: smoke-simulation

I am trying to create a simulation of smoke inside a building with Blender 2.73a. I have successfully modelled the building and created the smoke simulation. However, my smoke is not interacting with the walls of the building like it should. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot or render showing the problem?

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=129" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/129/)

Comment: Welcome romain :) Please start with the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour. You want to make the smoke interacts with the walls right?

Comment: Yes i want it! Can you help me

Answer (score 2):

You have a normal collision above the Smoke collision, and it seems to be messing things up. I removed both and re-added just the smoke collision, and the simulation appeared to work flawlessly, no smoke came outside of the walls.

**Before:**

[image: First Sim]

**After:**

[image: After Sim]

I can replicate this issue by adding a standard collision to the object, *then* adding the smoke collision. If you reverse the order it works perfectly fine. This appears to be some sort of collision priority conflict or bug. As long as you **add the Smoke Collision first** it should work as expected.

Comment: hello,
Thank you for you help! But, my problem is inside...i have an empty space between smoke and walls... Do you have a solution?

Comment: The resolution is very low, did you try increasing that?

Comment: Yes, but it's the same...

Comment: @romain I see what you mean, I'll look and see what I come up with

Comment: OK, thank you  NoviceInDisguise. I look too

Comment: I need help please...

Comment: @romain I can't even get your smoke sim to render, it appears to be set up wrong. I am not sure if the issue is just how the smoke is displayed int eh viewport or not. You might want to try a few tutorials. [**This one looks pretty good**](https://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/09/20/working-obstacles-smoke-simulations-blender/). Let me know if that helps, and please update your .blend if you have any further issues